# Loading Spinner React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am showing the progress bar till the post call to the API is loading. What i want is, if the api call fails, please navigate the control to the other page saying your connection request is failed.and if the post call is passed, i want to navigate it to success page. I have written the code for success page. How to write it in case of API failure.
Method:

```
this.setState({ loading: true });

this.sampleService.postCall(/* requestBody */)
  .then((response) => {
     const loading = this.state;
     this.setState({ loading: false });

     console.log(response);
     if(loading) {
       this.props.history.push("/success");
     }
   })
   .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simply `history.push` in the `catch` function.

Comment: its not working, after the api gets fail, i am still seeing the progress spinner.  .catch((error) => {
          this.props.history.push("/failure")
          console.log(error)});

Comment: Well lets define `api failure` then. What do you mean by failure.? wats the status code.. or response you expect from the API. ?

Comment: @Singh in your comment, you should set `loading` state to false.

Comment: i am setting loading: false,  .catch((error) => {
          console.log("error",error)
          this.setState({
            loading: false,
          });
          this.props.history.push("/failure")}); Still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the `then` as `success` and `catch` as `fail`. This means the code for a failed request should be in the `catch` block. I am using a function I called `notifyError`. The `samplService` should reject the Promise if the API call fails.
More about this in the [Promises documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise).

```js
this.setState({ loading: true });

this.sampleService.postCall(/* requestBody */)
  .then((response) => {
     this.setState({ loading: false });

     // I don't need to know if there is a loading state 
     // to navigate to the next page
     this.props.history.push("/success");
   })
   .catch((error) => {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
      notifyError(error); // Handle the error here
   });
```

Comment: i understand your answer, but i want to navigate the component to different component as soon as the API call gets fail. Can you help me with that

Comment: steps = [
      {
        name: "Step1",
        component: <Step1 />,
      },
      { name: "Step2",
        component: <Step2 />,
      },
      {
        name: "Step3",
        component: <Step3 />,
      },
      {
        name: "Step4",
        component: <Step4 />,
      },
      {
        name: "Step5",
        nextButtonText: "Save",
        component: <Step5 />,
      },
      { name: 'Save', component: <FinishedStep/>, isFinishedStep: true }
    ];

Comment: This is my UI code I am using a wizard. and on click of last step of wizard, I am doing the API call, if it fails i want to go to /failure page. Do i need an if condition in the last step, where I Am setting isFinishedStep: true ?

Comment: If redirecting in the `catch` statement does not work I belive the error is in the sampleService. SampleService should reject the promise if the request fails.

Comment: catch((error) => {
          console.log("error", error);
          this.setState({
            finishedStep: false,
          });
          this.props.history.push("<Sample/>");
        });

Comment: how can i navigate it to my sample component, if finishedStep is false